# Oracle compare tables to the previous day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been tasked with comparing some tables in my DB with how they were the previous day, in terms of number of rows mainly.
I guess I could write manually a procedure storing the number of rows in the tables and then going the day after and comparing against the stored numbers looking for unexpected variations, but.
Is there any standard way in Oracle that would do this in a cleaner way?

Comment: I would add something like a `creation_time` to the table and be done with it. Simple, fast, and clean.

Comment: I would have no access to modifying the source tables.

Comment: Also: I would like to have some control on the data quality, not just the creation time. The table is fully refreshed every time (not just new entries added).

Comment: You can use `after insert` and `after update` triggers. It's the cleanest way I can think of.

Comment: If you have [appropriate settings and rights](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-779FB434-F3EA-4334-8B2A-A328555B5AFF) you may use flashback query (with limited time travel interval) to retrieve the data as of timestamp in the past and compare it with the current data.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about some dayly table statistics and if you have a date column in your table that you can use (date of document or update or insert or....) you could try something like here:

```sql
Select DISTINCT
          d.TABLE_DATE,
          Sum(CASE WHEN t.DELIVERY_DATE <  d.TABLE_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By d.TABLE_DATE Order By d.TABLE_DATE DESC) "ROWS_BEFORE",
          Sum(CASE WHEN t.DELIVERY_DATE =  d.TABLE_DATE - 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By d.TABLE_DATE Order By d.TABLE_DATE DESC) "ROWS_YESTERDAY",
          Sum(CASE WHEN t.DELIVERY_DATE =  d.TABLE_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By d.TABLE_DATE Order By d.TABLE_DATE DESC) "ROWS_TODAY",
          Sum(CASE WHEN t.DELIVERY_DATE <= d.TABLE_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(Partition By d.TABLE_DATE Order By d.TABLE_DATE DESC) "TOTAL_ROWS",
          TRUNC(SYSDATE) "REPORTING_DATE"
From      dates d
Left Join tbl t ON(1 = 1)
Order By  d.TABLE_DATE DESC
```

If we try it with data like below:

```sql
WITH
     tbl(ID, ITEM_ID, ITEM_NAME, DELIVERY_DATE )  AS
        ( 
            Select  1 "ID",   1 "ITEM_ID", 'Item 1' "ITEM_NAME", To_Date('24.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "DELIVERY_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select  2,   1, 'Item 1', To_Date('21.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            
            Select  3,   1, 'Item 1', To_Date('20.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select  4,   1, 'Item 1', To_Date('20.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select  5,   1, 'Item 1', To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            
            Select  3,   2, 'Item 2', To_Date('19.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select  4,   3, 'Item 3', To_Date('18.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select  5,   3, 'Item 3', To_Date('23.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select  6,   3, 'Item 3', To_Date('22.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual 
       ),
      dates AS
        (   Select TRUNC(SYSDATE) - (LEVEL - 1) "TABLE_DATE" From DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7  )
```

| ID | ITEM_ID | ITEM_NAME | DELIVERY_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Item 1 | 24-JAN-23 |
| 5 | 3 | Item 3 | 23-JAN-23 |
| 6 | 3 | Item 3 | 22-JAN-23 |
| 2 | 1 | Item 1 | 21-JAN-23 |
| 3 | 1 | Item 1 | 20-JAN-23 |
| 4 | 1 | Item 1 | 20-JAN-23 |
| 3 | 2 | Item 2 | 19-JAN-23 |
| 5 | 1 | Item 1 | 19-JAN-23 |
| 4 | 3 | Item 3 | 18-JAN-23 |

... dates is a CTE defining how many days before sysdate you want to get.

R e s u l t :

| TABLE_DATE | ROWS_BEFORE | ROWS_YESTERDAY | ROWS_TODAY | TOTAL_ROWS | REPORTING_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26-JAN-23 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 25-JAN-23 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 9 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 24-JAN-23 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 9 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 23-JAN-23 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 22-JAN-23 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 7 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 21-JAN-23 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 26-JAN-23 |
| 20-JAN-23 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 5 | 26-JAN-23 |